# In an Azure DevOps pipeline, how to trigger and wait for another pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps, I got two pipelines:

- Pipeline A
- Pipeline B

Now, in PipelineA, I want to trigger PipelineB, and wait for PipelineB to finish. In the case that PipelineB succeeds, PipelineA shall go on, in case PipelineB fails, PipelineA shall fail, too.

[Here is an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#dependencies) where a pipeline job will depend on another. I want the same mechanism, but to depend on the run of another pipeline.

```
jobs:
- job: Debug
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from the Debug build
- job: Release
  dependsOn: Debug
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from the Release build
```

Comment: You can use a PowerShell/Bash script to poll the Azure DevOps API till the last build is completed, see [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/prevent-parallel-execution-of-the-same-build-defin/365730#T-N859271). I also achieved something similar but with a slightly different use case.